# кто может подсказать с bat в блокноте

Tags: bat

можно ли чтоб батник сам себя добавил в авто загрузку 
+ в батнике была команда shutdown 
получится ли так что комп будет вырубатся при запуске?
пропустит ли антивирус?
ля буду очень благодарен)

Comment: xcopy используй и в качестве пути что то вроде .\твойбатник.bat, а shutdown если мне не изменяет память требует прав администратора (Vista+ системы), так что врятли у тебя чет выйдет таким макаром

Answer (score 1):

Я надеюсь вам это не для старта создания вирусов.
Открываете **C:\Users\ваше имя\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup**
и закидываете сюда файл или ярлык

или <kbd>Win</kbd>`+`<kbd>R</kbd> инструмент «Выполнить», впишите в него такую команду: `shell:startup` и нажмите «ОК»

А так автоматически закинете файл в автозагрузку:

```
copy /y %~f0% %USERPROFILE%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\ >nul
```

Успехов в благих делах!